# in Wifi Direct the group owner address always be 192.168.49.1 or it changes?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, wifi-direct

in Wifi Direct the group owner address always be 192.168.49.1 or it changes?

I'm new to android. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

cheers.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be IP address 192.168.49.1.Due to DHCP it will change-unless you have a static IP.

Comment: This is wrong and doesn't answer the question. The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35288969/6844926) is correct - specifically 
`USB is  192.168.42.1 and 255.255.255.0`, 

`Wifi hotspot is 192.168.43.1 and 255.255.255.0`, 

`BT is limited to max default of 5 connections. 192.168.44.1 to 192.168.48.1 with 255.255.255.0`, 

`P2P is 192.168.49.1 and 255.255.255.0`

Answer (score 2):

Though I strongly believe that there should be no implementation where you need to directly rely on the `IP Address` of the `GroupOwner`, according to [Android Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/84befe36af491f26ae46243017a1aca4dd5b24d5/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pServiceImpl.java#233)(Search for `SERVER_ADDRESS` in the file) the `IP Address` of the `GroupOwner` is `192.168.49.1` and is `final and static`.

**Word of Caution:** This might get changed anytime in the future, and hence, you must never rely on the value itself. You should always use [isGroupOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDevice.html#isGroupOwner()) to find out whether a device is `GroupOwner` or not.

Comment: thanks for this. and is there a code to get the group owner IP?